# Remove multiple possible suffixes

Tags: shell, basename

Example: I want to create a quick command to shrink images (for my filebrowser).

```
...
FN="/tmp/some-image.jpg"
gm convert "$FN" -resize 50% "$(dirname $FN)/$(basename $FN .jpg/png/gif).jpg"
...
```

How can I specify that more than one suffix should be stripped?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`basename` only takes one suffix to remove, and gives the base name (removes the directory components) which you don't want there anyway, so `basename` is not really the right tool for your need.

The traditional tool to extract data  from a string is `expr`:

```
FN_without_extension=$(expr "x$FN" : 'x\(.*\)\.')
```

But modern shells (like `zsh`, `bash`, `ksh`, `ash`, `yash`, all POSIX compliant `sh`...) have builtin operators for that, so you hardly ever need `expr` nowadays (and it's best avoided as it's got a few issues).

```
${var%pattern}
```

removes the (smallest) part matching pattern from the end of `$var`

```
gm convert "$FN" -resize 50% "${FN%.*}.jpg"
```

Shells like `tcsh` or `zsh` have operators to remove extensions. Zsh:

```
gm convert $FN -resize 50% $FN:r.jpg
```

(`r` for *rootname*).

If you want to remove the extension, only if it's one of jpg/png/gif, then that becomes more complicated and shell dependant.

With `zsh`:

```
gm convert $FN -resize 50% ${FN%.(jpg|png|gif)}.jpg
```

With `ksh`:

```
gm convert "$FN" -resize 50% "${FN%.@(jpg|png|gif)}.jpg"
```

With `bash`:

```
shopt -s extglob
gm convert "$FN" -resize 50% "${FN%.@(jpg|png|gif)}.jpg"
```

With `expr`:

```
gm convert "$FN" -resize 50% "$(
  expr \( "x$FN" : '\(.*\)\.png$' \| \
          "x$FN" : '\(.*\)\.jpg$' \| \
          "x$FN" : '\(.*\)\.gif$' \| "x$FN" \) : 'x\(.*\)')".jpg
```

(yes, that's convoluted, and that's to work around some of the issues of `expr`).

With some `expr` implementations, it can be simplified to:

```
expr \( "x$FN" : '\(.*\)\.\(png\|jpg\|gif\)$' \| "x$FN" \) : 'x\(.*\)'
```

You could also use `sed`:

```
FN_without_ext=$(printf '%s\n' "$FN" |
  sed -e '$!b' -e 's/\.png$//;t' -e 's/\.gif$//;t' -e 's/\.jpg$//')
```

If you want it case insensitive, you can replace the `png/gif/jpg` in all those solutions above with `[pP][nN][gG]...`, some shells/tools can also do case insensitive matching:

`zsh`:

```
 setopt extendedglob
 FN_without_ext=${FN%.(#i)(gif|png|jpg)}
```

`ksh93`:

```
 FN_without_ext=${FN%.~(i:gif|png|jpg)}
```

`bash`:

```
 shopt -s nocasematch
 LC_ALL=C
 if [[ $FN =~ (.*)\.(gif|png|jpg)$ ]]; then
   FN_without_ext=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
 else
   FN_without_ext=$FN
 fi
```

GNU `sed`:

```
 FN_without_ext=$(printf '%s\n' "$FN" | sed -r '$s/\.(png|gif|jpg)$//I')
```

Comment: Shell dependency is a bummer. But it can’t be helped I guess.

Comment: Generally +1 for ${var%pattern}. I learned something new today.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick? It's basically removing `.mp3` or `.wav` extentions:

```bsh
$ basename -s .wav $(basename -s .mp3 'some_file.mp3')
some_file
$ basename -s .wav $(basename -s .mp3 'some_file.wav')
some_file
$ basename -s .wav $(basename -s .mp3 'some_file.rs') 
some_file.rs
```